# rails How to use reflection/introspection for attr_accessible on a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, reflection

I'm using Rails 3, so I'm using attr_accessible to white list attributes.  I want to be able to view the attributes listed for attr_accessible for a model and also to change them or even to remove attr_accessible from a model.

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
MyModel.class_eval{undef :attr_accessible}
```

which currently gives the error

```
undefined method `attr_accessible' for class `MyModel' (NameError)
```

Comment: I didn't understand your question. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The method you will should use will no longer work in rails 4. But you can try using `accessible_attributes`.

```
array = []
whitelisted_attributes = MyModel.last.accessible_attributes
whitelisted_attributes.each do |attr|
  array << attr if whitelisted_attributes.include?(attr)
end
array
```